I wish to use combined features in interact function of ipywidgets
I have this code where I generate a polynomial distribution for a dataset for multiple features one each, and what I want to do is to be able to include the combination of the features in the features parameter in the f function as follows :
def f(degree, test_data, features):
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data, y_data, test_size=test_data, random_state=1)
    lr = LinearRegression()
    order = range(1, degree+1)
    Rsqu_test = []
    for n in order:  # Corrected the range to use the 'degree' variable
        pr = PolynomialFeatures(degree=n)
        x_train_pr = pr.fit_transform(x_train[[features]])
        x_test_pr = pr.fit_transform(x_test[[features]])
        lr.fit(x_train_pr, y_train)
        Rsqu_test.append(lr.score(x_test_pr, y_test))
    def add_patch(legend):
        ax = legend.axes
        handles, labels = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()
        handles.append(Patch(facecolor='white'))
        labels.append(f"R²={Rsqu_test[-1]}")
        legend._legend_box = None
        legend._init_legend_box(handles, labels)
        legend._set_loc(legend._loc)
        legend.set_title(legend.get_title().get_text())
    xmax = max(x_train[[features]].values.max(), x_test[[features]].values.max())
    xmin = min([x_train[[features]].values.min(), x_test[[features]].values.min()])
    x = np.arange(xmin, xmax, 0.1)
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, figsize=(12, 15))
    ax1.plot(x_train[[features]], y_train, 'ro', label='Training Data')
    ax1.plot(x_test[[features]], y_test, 'go', label='Test Data')
    ax1.plot(x, lr.predict(pr.fit_transform(x.reshape(-1, 1))), label='Predicted Function')
    ax1.set_ylim([0, 6000])
    ax1.set_ylabel('Price')
    lgd = ax1.legend()
    add_patch(lgd)
    ax2.plot(order, Rsqu_test)  # Changed Rsqu_test to use the correct range
    ax2.set_xlabel('Degree')
    ax2.set_ylabel('R^2')
    ax2.set_title('R^2 Using Test Data')
    plt.show()
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
features = ['feature1','feature2',"'feature1','feature2'"]
interact(f, degree=(1, 15, 1), test_data=(0.05, 0.95, 0.05),features=features)

When I try to provide f a string like "'feature1,feature2'".
I get a key an error:
"None of [Index([''feature1', 'feature2''], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]".
I tried to format the string to get to be readable by the dataframe, but it didn't work. I am willing to include the combination in the interaction plot widget as part of the features list.
